# PrimeFaces JSF lightBox shows items in grid and modal too small

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, java-ee-7

### Environment:

JBoss EAP: 7.2.0
PrimeFaces Version: 8.0
Test Browsers: Chrome 85.0 & Edge 85.0

### Problem - `lightBox` Items in Grid:

I'm implementing PrimeFaces lightBox based on the documentation and showcase here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/lightBox.xhtml

I expect the `lightBox` to show a single image, and when clicked, opens a model that allows scrolling of other images in a bigger modal. However, my lightBox shows individual items in a vertical grid! See screenshot:

[image]

Here's my code for the `p:lightBox`:

```css
.lightbox-link {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/img/example-bg.png');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.w-inline-block {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rrsp-image-data-300px {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/img/example-bg.png');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- [START]: Supply Image        -->
<div class="lightbox-link w-inline-block w-lightbox">

  <p:lightBox id="lbxSupplyDetailImage">

    <h:outputLink value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" title="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}">
      <h:graphicImage value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" styleClass="rrsp-image-data-300px" alt="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}" />
    </h:outputLink>

    <h:outputLink value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" title="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}">
      <h:graphicImage value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" styleClass="rrsp-image-data-300px" alt="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}" />
    </h:outputLink>

    <h:outputLink value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" title="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}">
      <h:graphicImage value="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.lsSupplyImages.get(0).sSupplyImageFileURL}" styleClass="rrsp-image-data-300px" alt="#{controllerSupplies.clsSelectedSupply.sSupplyName}" />
    </h:outputLink>

  </p:lightBox>

</div>
<!-- [END]: Supply Image        -->
```

### Problem - `lightBox` modal too small:

**In addition**, when I click on a `p:lightBox` item to open the full image, it shows a very small modal, yet the image is 800x600px!
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Why I'm I facing these two problems? What could I be missing?

**Note:** I'm in the beginner learning stages of Java EE & JSF.

Comment: check which PF theme you are using.  I recommend using `nova-light` theme which is the same CSS theme the PF showcase uses.  Also try removing your custom CSS first and getting it working without it.